# A quotient of infinite direct product of field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring of countable infinite direct product of a field $F$ and $I$ be the countable infinite direct sum of $F$,clearly $I$ is an essential ideal of $R$.

Is $R$/$I$ an indecomposable $R$-module?
Is $R$/$I$ a cyclic $R$-module?
Is $I$ a maximal ideal in $R$?

I will be thankful for any clarification.

Comment: It is not maximal. The maximal ideals correspond to ultrafilters on the index set.

Comment: *every* quotient of a ring with identity is cyclic.

Comment: $R/I$ would be decomposable as an $R/I$ module, and hence also as an $R$ module.

Comment: @rschwieb Can I find an indecomposable module over  $R$ which is not simple?

Answer (score 1):

As it is a countable product we will asume that it is indexed in the natural.

1) We will put $e\in R$ such that $e_i=1_F$ if $i=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0_F$ otherwise, and $f\in R$ such that $f_i=1_F$ if $i=2k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0_F$ otherwise. It is clear that $1_R=e+f$, $e$ and $f$ are central idempotents orthogonals. Then $R=Re\oplus Rf$. Moreover $e+I$ and $f+I$ are central idempotents orthogonals non zero and $1_R+I=(e+I)+(f+I)$. Therefore $R/I=(R/I)(e+I)\oplus(R/I)(f+I)$.

2)As mentioned in the comments $R/I=R(1+I)$.

3) It is not maximal as $R/I$ is not a field, not even a integer domain $(e+I)(f+I)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am looking for an indecomposable module over $R$. Can I find such a module?